# MVC GET Controller with . [dot] value in PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, path-variables

Here is my spring boot controller

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}/{fileName}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Response getDocument(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String filename)
```

When a request is send with `fileName="test.docx"`, the controller pathvariable value is test (missing `.docx`). Is there anyway to get the parameters passed by the user?

I tried using

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}/{**fileName:.***}").
```

However, I got below status code 406 message on server (without even hitting the controller code path)

> "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException",
>     "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",

Spring boot version 1.5.7.RELEASE

Comment: The fix for the issue was 2 folds: 
1. use :.+ in the controller rest endpoint i.e. @GetMapping(value = "/{id}/{name:.+}")
and
2. Extend webmvcconfigurereadapter to override below method
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
 
Here is ref url: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Use `.+` like this

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/{fileName:.+}") 
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK) public Response getDocument(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String filename)
```